# Bootsfaces navbar open brand URL in a new tab

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I am using Bootsfaces 1.0.2 and JSF 2.2. If I wanted for the brandHref on the navBar component to open on a new tab, how could I accomplish this? In HTML I can use target=_blank but how would I be able to do the same with the navBar component in JSF? Is my only option using JavaScript?

```
<b:navBar
            brand="Brand"
            brandHref="http://www.google.com" inverse="false" position="bottom"
            sticky="false">

        </b:navBar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you open an issue on our bug tracker and ask us to add the `target` attribute with the next version of BootsFaces. BootsFaces 1.1.0 is currently in the ramp-up phase, so I'm afraid it's too late to include this feature with BootsFaces 1.1.0.

In the meantime, you can use a pass-through attribute. The disadvantage is that the pass-through attribute appears at every level of the navbar. To my surprise, I didn't observe problems caused by the ubiquitous `target` attribute, so you might give it a try:

```
<ui:fragment ...
  xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
  ...
  <b:navBar brand="BootsFaces" 
      brand-href="http://www.bootsfaces.net/" 
      pt:target="_blank">
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephan. I opened the issue here: https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/728